# Can i get database name with respect to schema name in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Hi i am trying to find the names of the database by specfying the name of the schema in snowflake

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to query the account usage view called SCHEMATA in the SNOWFLAKE database.

```
SELECT * FROM snowflake.account_usage.schemata WHERE schema_name = 'NAME-HERE';
```

I hope this helps...Rich

Comment: Note SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.SCHEMATA has a 2 hr latency

Comment: can you define "doesn't work"?  
Information about the account usage views can be found here:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html
If the query isn't working, giving you access errors, see the "Enabling Account Usage for Other Roles" section of that doc.
If "doesn't work" means the record is not found, it's likely what Waldente is saying, there is a delay, you may have to use a "show schemas like 'NAME-HERE' in account;" type of command - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-schemas.html

Comment: Note:  the show commands only show objects for which your current role has access privileges.